# No xdebug in phpinfo() for php 7.0.26 even though i have used the recommended compiler version download

Tags: php, xdebug

**I'm using XAMPP 3.2.2 my run status is as follows:**

```
10:00:47  [Apache]  Attempting to stop Apache (PID: 1908)
10:00:47  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
10:00:48  [mysql]   Attempting to stop MySQL app...
10:00:48  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
10:01:10  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
10:01:10  [Apache]  Status change 

detected: running
10:01:11  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
10:01:11  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
```

**Here are the instructions i followed:**

```
Installing Xdebug for XAMPP with PHP 7.x
Requirements
XAMPP for Windows: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
Setup
Download Xdebug for:

PHP 7.0.x: https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.0-vc14.dll (downloaded this)

Copy the file php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.0-vc14.dll to: C:\xampp\php\ext

Open the file C:\xampp\php\php.ini with Notepad++

Disable output buffering: output_buffering = Off

Scroll down to the [XDebug] section and copy this lines:

[XDebug]
zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.0-vc14.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_log="c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
; 3600 (1 hour), 36000 = 10h
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000

Stop/Start Apache
```

**here is a summary of the first block of phpinfo():**
[print of phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG13F.png)

**I have searched the rest of phpinfo() and cant find the [xdebug] section.**

What have i done wrong?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The first section clearly shows that Xdebug 2.5.5 is loaded. Which means that it really is and that there must be an Xdebug section in php.ini as well.